# C# issue connecting to MySQL Linux Database

Tags: c#, mysql, linux, database, connection

It's the first time I'm using **PuTTY** + **dedicated Linux Server**.

I have installed the **MySQL server client** on my **dedicated Linux server**:

```
apt-get install mysql-server
```

After installing, I had to set the MySQL Server password, which is what I did.
I have then created a database and a table, which I inserted one row into.

```
CREATE DATABASE frag_huans;

use frag_huans;

CREATE TABLE hero_data (
-> ID int(2),....);

INSERT INTO hero_data VALUES ('1',...);
```

this is literally **all I have done so far in regards to PuTTY**.

What I now tried to achieve, was **connecting to the database** via my C# Class (in Unity3D).

I've done this with my localhost (xampp) server and it worked fine.

```
string constr = "Server=localhost;Database=letzter;User ID=root;Password=;Pooling=true";
```

Now I wanted to connect to the Linux MySQL database the same way:

```
string constr = "Server=myServerIP;Database=frag_huans;Uid=root@serverIP;Pwd=myPassword";
```

where "myServerIP" is definitely my servers IP and the Uid is the ID that gets shown in PuTTY at the start of the command line.

**The connection won't set up**, Unity debugger prompting:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP, Boolean requireSocketPolicy) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket+Worker.Connect () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
HeroDB:Awake() (at Assets/Preload/HeroDB.cs:51)
```

Using another value at "Server=..." tells me that the host can't be found which ensures me that **my host address seems to be correct**.

I have also tried to **create another "user"** for the MySQL Server + **grant** this one **all privileges**:

```
CREATE USER fh@myServerIP IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on frag_huans.* to fh@myServerIP;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Changing the connection string to the user shown above didn't change the outcome.

I believe that the Linux server/MySQL database **blocks my access**. Is there any **privileges I have to set to the connection?** What could be a possible cause for this problem? I've seen many people having the "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it" - issue, but there seem to be too many different cases.

If you can help me in any way, I would be very happy

Thanks in advance, Cshaprest

Comment: Ensure that the server is listening on the port with a simple telnet, etc. to the IP address.  Be sure there are no firewall or routing rules that'd prevent the connection. Try running from a different machine just in case.

Comment: Can you connect to the database on your server from a client (HeidiSQL or the mysql command line client or something) running on the same machine as your C# code? That's an easier way to troubleshoot than running your code. Make sure the MySQL server is actually lstening for connections on a network interface other than `127.0.0.1`. (`netstat -anp | grep 3306` will tell you.) You may need to edit your `my.cnf` file to make that happen.

Comment: I have written "netstat -anp | grep 3306" into my putty (not as "mysql>"-command) and it indeed just prompts me the following: tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      31892/mysqld

Comment: cat /etc/mysql/my.cnf tells me that only 127.0.0.1 is the binded adress. Should I set another IP to it?

Comment: Setting the connection IP to 127.0.0.1 prompts the same error btw

Answer (score 1):

1. Try below commands from client machine `# telnet <serverip> 3306`
2. If first point fails, Check if there is Firewall rule to accept all incoming mysql connections on port 3306.
3. Server accept connections from all ip's if mysql id binded to 0.0.0.0 check it in /etc/my.cnf
4. It's just for confirmation , I assume you have added client IP[not the server IP] in below user creation command.

   `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on frag_huans.* to fh@myclientServerIP;
   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Comment: Thanks for the input, to be honest, i dont own this server and mysql server anymore, so i cant test it. But this is still helpful